# How can I create a newsletter signup similar to smartwater?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, newsletter

Sorry in advance if this is a dumb question.

I'm a beginner coder and having trouble creating a newsletter signup similar to Smartwater or Monster Energy Drink. They have their sign-up located in the footer, and once you enter your information, it gives you a confirmation message without redirecting you to a different page. I am trying to emulate that design but am stuck with the Javascript and CSS transitions.

HTML:

```
<section class="footerForm" style="padding: 10px;" id="newsletterSignup">
            
                
                <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><h1 style="color:#443627;">Come Along!</h1>Sign Up to our newsletter to hear our latest updates, promotions, and more.</legend><br>
                
                <label for="email">Email Address*</label><br>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required"><br>
                
                <label for="dob">Date Of Birth*</label><br>
                <select name="dob" size="1" required="required" id="month">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>January</option>
                    <option>Febuary</option>
                    <option>March</option>
                    <option>Abril</option>
                    <option>May</option>
                    <option>June</option>
                    <option>July</option>
                    <option>August</option>
                    <option>September</option>
                    <option>October</option>
                    <option>November</option>
                    <option>December</option>
                </select>
                <select name="dob" size="1" required="required" id="day">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>01</option>
                    <option>02</option>
                    <option>03</option>
                    <option>04</option>
                    <option>05</option>
                    <option>06</option>
                    <option>07</option>
                    <option>08</option>
                    <option>09</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>11</option>
                    <option>12</option>
                    <option>13</option>
                    <option>14</option>
                    <option>15</option>
                    <option>16</option>
                    <option>17</option>
                    <option>18</option>
                    <option>19</option>
                    <option>20</option>
                    <option>21</option>
                    <option>22</option>
                    <option>23</option>
                    <option>24</option>
                    <option>25</option>
                    <option>26</option>
                    <option>27</option>
                    <option>28</option>
                    <option>29</option>
                    <option>30</option>
                    <option>31</option>
                </select>
                
                <select name="dob" size="1" required="required" id="year">
                    <option>2023</option>
                    <option>2022</option>
                    <option>2021</option>
                    <option>2020</option>
                    <option>2019</option>
                    <option>2018</option>
                    <option>2017</option>
                    <option>2016</option>
                    <option>2015</option>
                    <option>2014</option>
                    <option>2013</option>
                    <option>2012</option>
                    <option>2011</option>
                    <option>2010</option>
                    <option>2009</option>
                    <option>2008</option>
                    <option>2007</option>
                    <option>2006</option>
                    <option>2005</option>
                    <option>2004</option>
                    <option>2003</option>
                    <option>2002</option>
                    <option>2001</option>
                    <option>2000</option>
                    <option>1999</option>
                    <option>1998</option>
                    <option>1997</option>
                    <option>1996</option>
                    <option>1995</option>
                    <option>1994</option>
                    <option>1993</option>
                    <option>1992</option>
                    <option>1991</option>
                    <option>1990</option>
                    <option>1989</option>
                    <option>1988</option>
                    <option>1987</option>
                    <option>1986</option>
                    <option>1985</option>
                    <option>1984</option>
                    <option>1983</option>
                    <option>1982</option>
                    <option>1981</option>
                    <option>1980</option>
                    <option>1979</option>
                    <option>1978</option>
                    <option>1977</option>
                    <option>1976</option>
                    <option>1975</option>
                    <option>1974</option>
                    <option>1973</option>
                    <option>1972</option>
                    <option>1971</option>
                    <option>1970</option>
                    <option>1969</option>
                    <option>1968</option>
                    <option>1967</option>
                    <option>1966</option>
                    <option>1965</option>
                    <option>1964</option>
                    <option>1963</option>
                    <option>1962</option>
                </select><br><br>
                <label for="tos">I agree to the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy of AguaVida</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="tos" name="tos"> <br>
                    
            </fieldset>
                <input type="button" value="Submit" class="button" id="newsletterButton">
            </form>
            
            <div class="confirmationNews">
                        <h3>You're all set! Wait for a confirmation email.</h3>
                    </div>
        </section>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes disappear{
    from{
        opacity: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0%;
        display:none;
    }
}

@keyframes appear{
    from{
        opacity: 0%;
        display:none;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 100%;
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

So far this is what I have. I have tried removing the action of "welcome.php", but it still attempts to redirect the user to a page that doesn't exist. I am stuck creating an appropiate css animation or javascript file that can allow me to show a confirmation message without changing the page. I want to confirm that they signed up while they aren't redirected to a different page (if that makes sense, my wording isn't the best).

All the help is appreciated.

Comment: One way to achieve what you are looking for it to use JavaScript. Listen for submit event for the form and prevent the default behavior of event which should disable the page reload/redirect, then you need to make POST request to your action URL using fetch Web API to the server. In the server, you perform the registration and send success/error message. After receiving a result back from the server, do some action in the frontend based on the result that you received.